# Is there a way to change an Oracle connection on the fly in Play! Framework?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, playframework, oracle11g

I currently work in a project where each user has his own schema in Oracle 11g DB. This design was done because all the security roles and privileges to access the Oracle tables are stored in the DB. Our team is trying to figure how to do this in the cool Play! framework. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can try wrap a value of `DB.datasource` with something like this (where `currentUser()` and `currentPassword()` should return the credentials of the current user who makes a request):

```
public class DataSourceWrapper {
    private DataSource original;
    public DataSourceWrapper(DataSource original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return original.getConnection(currentUser(), currentPassword());
    }

    ...

    public DataSource getOriginal() {
        return original;
    }
}
```

Replacement of `DB.datasource` should happen between execution of `onApplicationStart()` methods of DB and JPA plugins, so that you need to create a custom plugin:

```
public class DataSourceReplacementPlugin extends PlayPlugin {
    public void onApplicationStart() {
        DB.datasource = new DataSourceWrapper(DB.datasource);
    }

    public void onApplicationStop() {
        if (DB.datasource instanceof DataSourceWrapper) {
            DB.datasource = ((DataSourceWrapper) DB.datasource).getOriginal();
        }
    }
}
```

and register in with the appropriate priority level in `conf/play.plugins`:

```
350: DataSourceReplacementPlugin
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I hesitated of this because of the static `DB.datasource`.Isn't that going to kill concurrency?

Comment: AsemRadhwi: What do you mean? Connections are obtained from the datasource per request, and, as far as I understand you problem, you need to obtain connections for different users in each request, right?

Comment: That is correct. I need to get different connections depending on the user's Oracle credentials. The connection could be stored in the user's session if the user is still logged on to the system, and will be destroyed if he is logged out.

Comment: @AsemRadhwi: Play obtains a new connection by calling `getConnection()` for each request, so that the solution above should be correct (if it works). Also, Play doesn't have sessions in the usual sense (due to its "share nothing" architecture), thus you can't store connections in it. Caching of connections is performed by a pooling datasource.

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you soon here! Appreciate your response.

Comment: axtavt: Where this code should reside? I tried to put it in the Bootstrap, but the app is complaining about an empty connection because of the DBPlugin and JPAPlugin